# Setting Excel cell content based on row font color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I'm trying to migrate into SQL.

The spreadsheet contains 65k rows of information over two worksheets.

The people operating the spreadsheet have been colouring the font in the rows either red, blue or yellow depending on the status of the record. Each row is a record with personal data etc. so I can't share online.

As part of the migration to SQL I need to add a column with a status field. The status field on each row should contain either 1, 2, 3, or 4 depending on whether the row has a black, red, blue or yellow font.

Based on searching here I believe it might be possible with a VBA function and a formula?

Could anyone help with what to do? I'm ok with Excel but not a power user by any means.

Comment: If all the row will have the same font color, checking the A:A values will be enough I suppose. Then, how do you intend to use these 1, 2, 3, 4 values? Creating a function to return an array of all your range, in terms of the above font colors logic, will be OK? If not, will  adding a new column after the used range be more appropriate? Then, talking about "over two worksheets" do you need a global solution including both of them, or for only a worksheet? Then, the color blue, let us say, is a little vague  for VBA... Are you sure that the user will use the same red, blue, yellow?

Comment: I'd not suggest a function. They do not update themselves when the font is changed. A subroutine should be safer in my opinion.

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey: What do you mean by "do not update themselves"? The function will return the real status in the moment when it is called. The same for what you name 'a subrutine'''.

Comment: Exaclty: same as subroutine. And in both cases, if you change the font the output wont' change unless you re-run the function/subroutine. Therefore the result is the same while the user might think that once the font is changed the function will refresh the result. Since that's not the case, i'd say it's better to write it as a subroutine and make the user run it once the user needs it.

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey:  What does "I'd not suggest a function. They do not update themselves when the font is changed." means? What do you suggest "will by adapted by itself"? A subrutine? If not, what is the meaning of your comment?

Comment: Didn't i just explained it? I'll try again: the user is probably more accustomed with function than with subroutine. Whenever he uses a formula like `=SUM(A:A)` he is expecting it to react to any changes in the values of column A. That will happend because the formula will actually react to values' changes. That's not the same with formats. If we give our user a function to complete this task (return the font color) there is a chance that he will expect it to react to any changes in the font color. Since that's not the case, this constitutes a risk. Did i explained myself?

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey:  I am afraid that you make a confusion between a function (I am talking about) and a **UDF function** (one able to return something in a cell, called in a formula). They are different issues. I think we spent too much time for such a simple issue. I wish you a good day!

Comment: I'll take a look. In any case thank you for all your concerns. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for all the help!

It seems there is a very simple way to do this without any code!

I was able to use the filter function by highlighting the cheet and sorting by colour. Once I had all the red text together I was able to just add a 1 to each row and fill down.

Comment: And what about blue and yellow? Are you the one filling the font color? If not, how can you be sure that the user will always fill the same color nuance? Especially for blue, which shows more such nuances? Calling a function will do it very fast when you need it. And (my) function checks more nuances.

Comment: We are moving the users from the spreadsheet to a web/sql system and stopped editing the worksheet. They have been colouring the rows and I'm using the colours to set the record type in the export/migration once done we are binning the excel sheet.

Comment: I was talking about that "once done". How do you know that they did it using the same color nuance? And what about blue and yellow? Do you try suggesting that manually filtering and allocating numbers would be more convenient than a function doing this automatically? If yes, I do not have a problem, even if my opinion is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

try using something like this in VBA. You will need to add several more ifs based on the colors you have.

```
CurrentSheetText="Sheet1"
LastRow = Sheets(CurrentSheetText).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
for iter = 1 to LastRow
if Sheets(CurrentSheetText).Cells(iter, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
Sheets(CurrentSheetText).Cells(iter,5).value =1
End if

Next iter
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub SubColor()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngColouredRange As Range
    Dim RngFirstAnswer As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim DblRow As Double
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set RngColouredRange = Range("M1:M5")
    Set RngFirstAnswer = Range("N1")
    
    'Covering each cell in RngColouredRange.
    For Each RngTarget In RngColouredRange
        
        'Checking font's color.
        Select Case RngTarget.Font.Color
            'In Case is black.
            Case Is = 0
                RngFirstAnswer.Offset(DblRow, 0) = 0
            'In case is red.
            Case Is = 255
                RngFirstAnswer.Offset(DblRow, 0) = 1
            'In case is blue.
            Case Is = 12611584
                RngFirstAnswer.Offset(DblRow, 0) = 2
            'In case is yellow.
            Case Is = 65535
                RngFirstAnswer.Offset(DblRow, 0) = 3
            'In other cases.
            Case Else
                RngFirstAnswer.Offset(DblRow, 0) = "Unclassified"
        End Select
        
        'Increasing DblRow.
        DblRow = DblRow + 1
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Edit the variables accordingly.

If you need to know what number refers to each of the fonts' color you have, use this:

```
Sub SubFontColourNumber()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngColouredRange As Range
    Dim RngFirstAnswer As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim DblRow As Double
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set RngColouredRange = Range("M1:M5")
    Set RngFirstAnswer = Range("N1")
    
    'Covering each cell in RngColouredRange.
    For Each RngTarget In RngColouredRange
        
        'Reporting the font's color.
        RngFirstAnswer.Offset(DblRow, 0) = RngTarget.Font.Color
        
        'Increasing DblRow.
        DblRow = DblRow + 1
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Like before, edit the variables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily implemented with VBA. Due to the lack of information in the post, I can only write you a crude script

```
Sub AddCol()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long

'Target workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("NAME")
'Target worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets(INDEX)
'Target column
target_col = 1
'Output column
output_col = 10

With ws
    'Find last row in sheet based on column A
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through row 1 through LRow
    For i = 1 To LRow
        'populate output col based on target col's font colour
        If .Cells(i, target_col).Font.Color = vbBlack Then
            .Cells(i, output_col).Value = 1
        ElseIf .Cells(i, target_col).Font.Color = vbRed Then
            .Cells(i, output_col).Value = 2            
        ElseIf .Cells(i, target_col).Font.Color = vbBlue Then
            .Cells(i, output_col).Value = 3
        ElseIf .Cells(i, target_col).Font.Color = vbYellow Then
            .Cells(i, output_col).Value = 4
        End If            
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next function, please. It will return an array with the settled codes for analyzed colors. It take in consideration all standard nuances (especially for blue) of the colors in discussion:

```
Function colorNo(sh As Worksheet) As Variant
  Dim lastR As Long, cel As Range, arr, k As Long
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  ReDim arr(lastR - 2)
  For Each cel In sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
        Select Case cel.Font.Color
            Case vbRed, 49407: arr(k) = 2: k = k + 1
            Case vbBlue, 12611584, 6567712, 9851952, 14395790: arr(k) = 3: k = k + 1
            Case vbYellow: arr(k) = 4: k = k + 1
            Case Else: arr(k) = 1: k = k + 1
        End Select
  Next
  colorNo = arr
End Function
```

The above code considers all other colors like being Black!

If in the future you will need some other colors, you should fill appropriate `Case newColor` lines...

It can be tested/used in this way:

```
Sub testColorNo()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrCol As Variant
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  arrCol = colorNo(sh)
  'the array can be used like it is
  'or its value can be dropped in the last empty column
  'un comment the next line if you want to visually see the returned array
  'but only on testing small range. Otherwise, it will be a huge string...
  'Debug.Print Join(arrCol, ","): you can see the array content in Immediate Window
  sh.cells(2, sh.UsedRange.Columns.count + 1).Resize(UBound(arrCol) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                                         WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrCol)
End Sub
```